# compare two tables's data in MySQL

Tags: mysql

There are two tables

### Table 1

```
select * from manage_tcp;
+----+----------+--------+
| id | services | statut |
+----+----------+--------+
|  2 |     1433 | up     |
|  2 |     3389 | up     |
|  3 |     3389 | down   |
|  3 |     1433 | down   |
|  9 |     3389 | up     |
|  8 |     3389 | up     |
|  7 |     1433 | up     |
|  6 |     3389 | up     |
|  5 |     3389 | up     |
|  4 |     3389 | up     |
| 10 |     1433 | up     |
| 11 |     1433 | up     |
| 12 |     3389 | up     |
| 13 |     1433 | up     |
| 14 |     3389 | up     |
| 15 |     1433 | up     |
| 16 |     3389 | up     |
| 17 |     1433 | up     |
| 18 |     3389 | up     |
| 19 |     1433 | up     |
| 20 |     3389 | up     |
| 21 |     1433 | up     |
| 24 |     1433 | up     |
| 23 |     3389 | up     |
| 25 |     3389 | up     |
| 26 |     1433 | up     |
| 29 |     1433 | up     |
| 28 |     3389 | up     |
| 30 |     3389 | up     |
| 31 |       80 | up     |
| 32 |     3389 | up     |
| 33 |       80 | up     |
| 34 |     3389 | up     |
| 35 |       80 | up     |
+----+----------+--------+
34 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

### Table 2

```
mysql> select * from manage_host;
+----+------------+-------------+--------+-------+--------------+----------+------+
| id | uptime     | type        | statut | group | thresold_ref | thresold | mail |
+----+------------+-------------+--------+-------+--------------+----------+------+
|  2 |  277248529 | win2003.png | up     |     4 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
|  3 |  277277471 | win2003.png | prob   |     4 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
|  4 |  346159833 | win2003.png | up     |     4 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
|  5 |  930205491 | win2003.png | up     |     5 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
|  6 | 3805663007 | win2003.png | up     |     5 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
|  7 |         -1 | win2003.png | up     |     4 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
|  8 |   29413867 | win2003.png | up     |     5 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
|  9 |  981986401 | win2003.png | up     |     5 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
| 10 |         -1 | win2003.png | up     |     5 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
| 11 |         -1 | win2003.png | up     |     5 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
| 12 | 2230787611 | win2003.png | up     |     7 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
| 13 |         -1 | win2003.png | up     |     7 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
| 14 | 1004161923 | win2003.png | up     |     8 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
| 15 |         -1 | win2003.png | up     |     8 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
| 16 | 1592294954 | win2003.png | up     |     8 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
| 17 |         -1 | win2003.png | up     |     8 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
| 18 | 1449216250 | win2003.png | up     |     4 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
| 19 |         -1 | win2003.png | up     |     4 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
| 20 | 3461945234 | win2003.png | up     |     4 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
| 21 |         -1 | win2003.png | up     |     4 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
| 23 | 3461946968 | win2003.png | up     |     4 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
| 24 |         -1 | win2003.png | up     |     4 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
| 25 | 3462022562 | win2003.png | up     |     4 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
| 26 |         -1 | win2003.png | up     |     4 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
| 35 | 3318333401 | win2003.png | up     |     6 |            1 |        0 |      |
| 28 | 3461879984 | win2003.png | up     |     4 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
| 29 |         -1 | win2003.png | up     |     4 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
| 30 | 1872950109 | win2003.png | up     |     6 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
| 31 | 1872950125 | win2003.png | up     |     6 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
| 32 | 1955232033 | win2003.png | up     |     6 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
| 34 | 3318333401 | win2003.png | up     |     6 |            1 |        0 |      |
| 33 | 1955232049 | win2003.png | up     |     6 |            1 |        0 | NULL |
+----+------------+-------------+--------+-------+--------------+----------+------+
32 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'd like to compare those two tables above and to get the results in table 1 but not in table 2 like: (**this is the result i want**)

```
+----+----------+--------+
| id | services | statut |
+----+----------+--------+
|  2 |     1433 | up     |
|  3 |     3389 | down   |
|  3 |     1433 | down   |
+----+----------+--------+
```

I've tried

```
SELECT a.*,b.* 
FROM manage_tcp as a 
LEFT JOIN manage_host as b 
USING(id,statut) 
WHERE b.id is null;
```

but I got

```
+----+----------+--------+
| id | services | statut |
+----+----------+--------+
|  3 |     3389 | down   |
|  3 |     1433 | down   |
+----+----------+--------+
```

it's not what I want.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why would you repeat a table in the same database?  Sounds like a bad design to me.

Comment: How do you compare the two tables?

Comment: @duffymo Yes it's a bad design, but i got to get the answer of it.

Comment: @PetarMinchev yep, it's my question. of cause to use SQL.

Comment: Sounds like a LEFT JOIN on ID in a but not in b.

Comment: what is to be copmpared ? what should be the output ?

Comment: Elaborate ur requirement, as we know what you dont want, but tell us what u want?

Comment: `it's not what I want` What _do_ you want?

Comment: `2 | up` exists in both tables, why is it in result?

Comment: @vearutop : because it is twice in Table 1... My Guess...

Comment: did you guys see this line?
I'd like to compare those two tables above and to get the results in table 1 but not in table 2 like:

+----+----------+--------+
| id | services | statut |
+----+----------+--------+
|  2 |     1433 | up     |
|  3 |     3389 | down   |
|  3 |     1433 | down   |
+----+----------+--------+

Comment: @xxd : You want in sql or mysql? I see both tags. Please keep one tag which is required.

Comment: what the comparison column ? id and statut? or id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: (assume the comparison column are **id** and **statut**)

```
SELECT a.id, a.services, a.statut
    FROM manage_tcp a
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT b.id FROM manage_host b WHERE b.id=a.id AND b.statut=a.statut)
UNION
SELECT a.id, (SELECT services FROM manage_tcp WHERE id=a.id ORDER BY id LIMIT 1), a.statut
    FROM manage_tcp a 
    GROUP BY a.id, a.statut HAVING COUNT(1)>1
```

The first query will produce result from table a where not in table b.

The second, after UNION, will produce result for id that appear twice in table a.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT m.id, m.services, m.statut 
FROM manage_tcp m
WHERE EXISTS 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM manage_host mh 
    WHERE mh.id = m.id AND m.statut = mh.statut
)
```

This will give you the intersection of the tables `manage_tcp` and `manage_host` based on `id` and `status` columns.

> get the results in table 1 but not in table 2

If you need the difference between the tow tables, use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `EXISTS` like this:

```
SELECT m.id, m.services, m.statut 
FROM manage_tcp m
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM manage_host mh 
    WHERE mh.id = m.id AND m.statut = mh.statut 
)
```

Typically, this is the implementations of the `INTERSECT` and `EXCEPT` operators which are defined by the SQL standard as the set intersection and difference operators. But, unfortunately, most database system doesn't implement these operators. MS SQL Server does support these operators but not MYSQL .

Comment: Your answer is like the way I tried as I mentioned in my question. please check. I also need '|  2 |     1433 | up     |',because it is twice in Table 1. Thanks.

Comment: How do you know you need 2-1433-up and not 2-3389-up in result?

Comment: @vearutop,because it is twice in Table 1, if the 2-1433-up is show up 3 times in table 1 and only one time in table 2, the result will be like 2-1433-up,2-1433-up,3-3389-down,3-1433-down.

Comment: @xxd, the `2-1433-up` is shown only one time in table1, not 2, there is two with `2-up` but different services number's.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal, sorry, you are right. what I want to say is that the id 2 is twice in Table 1, so I got to display it. It doesn't matter what value of the other columns are. thanks

Comment: @xxd, Then you have to add more restrictions in the difference between two tables, because this way the value `2|up` is exists in the same table and won't be included in the result set, you have to find one more different indicator plus `status`, `id` to include the `2|1433|up` in the result set.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT manage_tcp.* FROM 
(
    SELECT a.id,a.statut,a.cnt
    FROM (
        SELECT id, statut, COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM manage_tcp GROUP BY id,statut
    ) AS a
    LEFT JOIN manage_host AS b USING(id, statut)
    GROUP BY a.id, a.statut
    HAVING a.cnt > COUNT(1)
) AS diff
LEFT JOIN manage_tcp USING(id,statut)
```

or

```
SELECT a.id,a.statut,a.services,a.cnt
FROM (
    SELECT id,statut,services,COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM manage_tcp GROUP BY id,statut
) AS a
LEFT JOIN manage_host AS b USING(id, statut)
GROUP BY a.id,a.statut
HAVING a.cnt > COUNT(1)
```

Comment: error from both of them: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'a.cnt' in 'having clause'. we can't do COUNT(1)? I also tried 'SELECT a.id,a.statut, COUNT(1) as cntt,a.cnt 
    FROM (
        SELECT id,statut,COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM manage_tcp GROUP BY id,statut
    ) AS a
    LEFT JOIN manage_host AS b USING(id, statut)
    GROUP BY a.id,a.statut
    HAVING a.cnt > cntt'  doesn't work

Comment: Seems Mysql optimizer drops 'unused' fields from derived tables. Updated queries, please try again.